# Flex: SWFloader complete event is not being fired

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, swfloader

I am getting a weird error, some of the flash files are loading but some others are not loading. There are no error message that are being shown.
Please let me know how to solve the issue.

Here is a example

```
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[   
protected function loader1_completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    vals.text=vals.text+"loaded test"
}
]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:SWFLoader id="loader" source="include/sumita_logo.swf"/>

<mx:SWFLoader id="loader1" complete="loader1_completeHandler(event)"
source="include/sumita.swf"/>

<mx:Label id="vals" text="Was here"/>
```

The issue is "loader" loads without error, but complete event for loader1 is not invoked and the label vals text remains "Was here". The SWF sumita.swf is also not loaded.

Comment: You have to give us more details. Code snippets, trace of the HTTP requests, and similar details may be helpful for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

in place of mx component try  out spark component . sample codes given below

```
<s:VGroup>
    <s:SWFLoader id="loader" source="./black.swf"/>
    <s:SWFLoader id="loader1" complete="loader1_completeHandler(event)" source="./blue.swf"/>

    <mx:Label id="vals" text="Was here"/>
</s:VGroup>


protected function loader1_completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
trace("loader1 loaded"); }
```